# Swift - Unable to retrieving data from Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, swift4

I am a beginner Swift programmer. I am learning to retrieve data from Firebase database.

The debug console showed:

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x11020b4f8) to 'NSString' (0x10f37b2a8).2018-03-26 15:49:25.442062+0800 messagingapp[4594:1197722] Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x11020b4f8) to 'NSString' (0x10f37b2a8)".

I have put a breakpoint at the end of the code and managed to confirm that `postDict` correctly retrieve data from snapshot. However, the array `postData` just could not append. Would appreciate if anyone could give me advice to overcome this. Many thanks

```
var postData = ["message 1", "message 2"]

postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

refHandle = postRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
    // ...

    for ( _, myvalue) in postDict {
        self.postData.append(myvalue as! String)

    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()       
})
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10b9b34f8) to 'NSString' (0x10ab232a8)." is shown at the debugger console.   It did not show up as an error though.

Comment: I have a screenshot, how do it upload it to stack exchange? I am new here

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49485499/edit) your question to include that information. In [the advanced help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) you can learn more about what you can do in your question including images.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `postDict` debugging console output, I guess you simply forgot to access the `"Posts"` key (before filling the corresponding `self.postData`). For instance:

```
let valueDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
let postDict = valueDict["Posts"] as? [String: String] ?? [:]
// ...

for (_, postString) in postDict {
    self.postData.append(postString)
}
```

By the way, you can further simplify your code by using the *trailing closure* syntax sugar as well:

```
refHandle = postRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
    /* observer body */
}
```